# when to throw exception if illegal argument passed to an API method?

Tags: java, exception

See the two examples below. Assume both classes contains public methods belonging to a widely used API library.

`AClass.java` is easier to write (maybe easier to read due to less noise), but when error is detected, the first method in stack trace is an internal method (`nullCheck(...)`) and the exception message is not referring to that method. Could this cause unnecessary confusion to the user? I mean in the sense of the user thinking: "it's an internal method which has thrown an exception, must be a bug in the library, not a fault in my program. What a **** useless library..."

`BClass.java` is more tiresome to write (with all its if statements), but when error is detected the first line of the stack trace pinpoints the API method (called by user) where error was first detected. Would this more likely make user think: "I'm calling that method from my code, must be something wrong with the parameter I'm passing in".

Which would be the preferred way of throwing exception when checking parameters for validity in a public API? Or are the two examples considered equal?

```
public class AClass {
public void publicApiMethod1(String a){
    nullCheck(a, "a");
    // do something...
}
public void publicApiMethod2(String a, String b, String c){
    nullCheck(a, "a");
    nullCheck(b, "b");
    nullCheck(c, "c");
    // do something...
}

private void nullCheck(Object a, String argName) {
    if(a == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null argument: " + argName);
    }
}
}


public class BClass {
public void publicApiMethod1(String a){
    if(a == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null argument: 'a'");
    }
    // do something...
}

public void publicApiMethod2(String a, String b, String c){
    if(a == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null argument: 'a'");
    }
    if(b == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null argument: 'b'");
    }
    if(c == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null argument: 'c'");
    }
    // do something...
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If your error message is descriptive (and it is), no one will bother to look at the stack trace. Thus the first form is better because it encapsulates the validation logic.

Note that there are plenty of assertion methods in various libraries ready to use, see: [`Objects.requireNonNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull%28T,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Validate.notNull`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html#notNull%28T,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)).

Answer (score 2):

I would do it that way, basically based on your `AClass`:

```
public void publicApiMethod2(String a, String b, String c){
    try {
        nullCheck(a, "a");
        nullCheck(b, "b");
        nullCheck(c, "c");
    }
    // catch the NullPointerException,
    // and any other Exception explicitly thrown by your validation methods
    catch (NullPointerException e) { 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
    }
    // do something...
}
```

That way, the user gets an explicit message **and** a stacktrace that points to the public method.

Comment: +1 for the stacktrace and NPE->IAE. But why do you catch all Exceptions? I'd rather only catch NPE (and add the NPE as IAE's cause.

Comment: @DaveBall as per your suggestion and another user's, I've modified the `catch`clause. However, and it's just a matter of personal taste, I'd rather not expose more of the internals of the private methods. After all, we are talking about building a public API here...

Comment: Not good practice IME. What if you catch a NPE which you're not expecting? You'll have lost its original stack trace and it's message could well be null - so you'll have an IAE with no cause and a null message - yuck

Comment: @davidfrancis I totally agree, and if it were totally up to me, I wouldn't make the `nullCheck()` methods throw NPEs, but rather some kind of checked exception. But I prefered to stick to the OP's already in place implementation.

Answer (score 1):

in your b class why dont you use

```
if( (c == null)|| (b == null)|| (a == null) ){
 //thrown my red ball
 }
```

less tiresome, more readable

Comment: but then you can't determine which varaible is `null`

Comment: it's needed if you want to have an explanatory error message. and yes, you could summarize all X vars, but it can quickly get out of hand if you start having too many variables to check...

Answer (score 1):

I would think that Class A is fine, as long as you clearly document it with a `@throws`. I have seen plenty of libraries that will throw deeper in the stack. The important thing is for the user to understand WHY an error was thrown and what they can do to avoid it.